# Console application closes immediately after opening in visual studio

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, console

I am trying to open a console application in visual studio built in C#. As soon as I open it, it closes immediately.

I know windows sets this is a a safety default (atleast I think). How do I fix this?

I know I can compile it and create a shortcut and modify the target so it has the location of the command prompt in it before the applications location. Although the programmer who created this has it generating information into the output of visual studio, so it's imperative that  I only open it there.

It happens with most applications and not just in visual studio, just in this case I need it to open in VS 2010. I am using Windows 7.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is an ancient problem and has inspired several funny cartoons:

[image]

Let's fix it.  What you want to do is prompt the user to press the Any key when the console app was started from a shortcut on the desktop, Windows Explorer or Visual Studio.  But not when it was started from the command processor running its own console.  You can do so with a little pinvoke, you can find out if the process is the sole owner of the console window, like this:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine("Working on it...");
        //...
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        PressAnyKey();
    }

    private static void PressAnyKey() {
        if (GetConsoleProcessList(new int[2], 2) <= 1) {
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetConsoleProcessList(int[] buffer, int size);
}
```

Comment: Not if all one wants is a quick way to pause at the end of a run from VS. for a small utility or for test code, pinvoke might be more of a hassle than remembering 'Debugger.IsAttached'.

Comment: That's just your opinion, this is copy/paste code written to never be a hassle.  Please do feel free to show your preference in your own post.

Answer (score 9):

You can also run the application by pressing (Ctrl + F5) .. This will allow it to run in 'Release' mode, and by default, you will need to press 'return' to close the window.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of Main() method. This is a quick and dirty way of stopping the window from closing by itself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for user input. Use either `Console.ReadLine()`, `Console.Read()`, or `Console.ReadKey()`.

Answer (score 1):

So, according to [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160125-00/?p=92922)

> If your process is the only one attached to the console, then the
> console will be destroyed when your process exits. If there are other
> processes attached to the console, then the console will continue to
> exist (because your program won’t be the last one).

And if we adapt the code to C# you would end up something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CheckIfConsoleWillBeDestroyedAtTheEnd
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ...

            if (ConsoleWillBeDestroyedAtTheEnd())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        private static bool ConsoleWillBeDestroyedAtTheEnd()
        {
            var processList = new uint[1];
            var processCount = GetConsoleProcessList(processList, 1);

            return processCount == 1;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetConsoleProcessList(uint[] processList, uint processCount);
    }
}
```