# Output screen disappears suddenly in C# console application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am writing a simple C# console application in VS 2013 but the problem is that output screen flashes for a moment and disappears suddenly . I use the alternate way and write Console.Readline() method in the end and problem is fixed .So but i personally think that this is just a trick to stop the screen and not the proper way.So can anyone explain me the proper way of doing this ??

Comment: It's totally normal. Program has finished execution and closed. If you like to see some information - you do Console.Readline()/or ReadKey() for example

Comment: You get a preview of what happens when you create a shortcut to your program on the desktop.  Flash, bang, gone.  The proverbial "Hit any key to continue" message, with the user calling you to ask where the Any key is located, is the normal workaround.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Console application closes immediatly after opening in visual studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255832/console-application-closes-immediatly-after-opening-in-visual-studio)

Comment: There are plenty of good answers below. Don't forget to mark the question as answered if you like the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program immediately closes because there's nothing stopping it from closing. Insert a breakpoint at `return 0;` or add `Console.Read();` before `return 0;` to prevent the program from closing.

> After you are done with your program, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> ( Run without
>   debugging). This will prompt before closing the window and this is
>   what you want.

**Or** use this line at the end

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: If you hit Ctrl + F5 to run it in release mode, it is not necessary to add any Console.Read() line to make the program wait for user input. The screen just stays there.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is the correct way of doing it. `Console.ReadLine()` and `Console.ReadKey()` are a blocking statement: they halt the thread to wait for input before continueing. If you wouldn't do this the program would reach its end and thus exit the console.

In a larger console program you might have a `while(running)` loop instead and a GUI won't have this problem until its GUI thread is explicitly stopped (closing the window), but for a simple console app you can just use this 'trick'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you don't stop the application it keeps running and ends when done processing.

That's why you need the `Console.ReadLine()`, it stops processing and waits until you tell it to continue.

Answer (score 0):

when you run the program in Debug mode if you do'nt have any BreakPoints or if .NET engine does not need to Read IO from user then it just finishes the excution without waiting anymore.

if you want to stop the execution at the end want to see the console screen you can either use any IO Read Statements as below:

```
Console.ReadLine();
Console.Read();
Console.ReadKey();
```

OR

You can run your program in `without Debugging` mode by simply pressing `Ctrl+F5`