# Why does VB close the console window too soon?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm learning visual Basic, and i want to show a windows console with `Hola mundo`, like this:

```
Module Greeting

   Sub Main()
       Console.WriteLine('Hola mundo')
   End Sub

End Module
```

But it run program, and show windows console and close fast, Why ? , something missed ?

Comment: You should wait for a keypress.

Comment: @the4kmanI, don't know to do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255832/console-application-closes-immediatly-after-opening-in-visual-studio/13256385#13256385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB closes the console as soon as the program is terminated, i.e. the last statement in `Sub Main()` was executed. Therefore add a command waiting for a key press

```
Console.WriteLine('Hola mundo')
Console.ReadKey()
```

Now the console stays open until the user presses some key. If you want him to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead, replace `Console.ReadKey()` by `Console.ReadLine()`.