# C# console app closes itself after I run it

Tags: c#, console-application

When I run this simple application it closes itself without reason. How to prevent that?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 10;
            int b = 20;
            int c = a * b;

            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put `Console.ReadLine();` at the end

Comment: I'm guessing you mean that it closes itself when you debug it. Add a `Console.ReadLine()` at the end.

Comment: I already wrote the answer.

Comment: You need the proverbial "press any key to continue" so you can look at the console before it closes.  But only when you run it in the debugger, from a desktop shortcut or Explorer.  And not when you run it from the command line processor, what console mode apps were designed to do.  Support either way with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256385/17034).

Comment: thanks for answer! can you please click upvote for answer, because i dont have enough points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `Console.ReadKey();` after printing the value.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 10;
            int b = 20;
            int c = a * b;

            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```