# How do I stop my C# console program from stopping when executing "console.readline();" twice

Tags: c#

i'm really new to C# and i've been working on this really simple command line style program (that has custom commands and such). Now the commands work great but every time I allow the user to go back to enter another command or just anything it closes the program when I press enter. But only the second time I execute a command. I think this has something to do with console.WriteLine();

Here's my code (I've searched everywhere on how to fix this and nothing that i've found has worked)

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleProgram
{
class Program
{
    private static string userEnteredCommand;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "IAO Systems Service Console";
        onCommandLineStart();

        void onCommandLineStart()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Copyright (C) 2018 IAO Corporation");
            Console.WriteLine("IAO Systems Service Console (type 'sinfo' for more information.");
            userEnteredCommand = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        void onCommandLineReturn()
        {
            userEnteredCommand = Console.ReadLine();
        }


        // Commands

        if (userEnteredCommand == "sinfo")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("Program information:");
            Console.WriteLine("Created for IAO Corporation, by Zreddx");
            Console.WriteLine("This program controls doors, gates and e.t.c within IAO Terratory.");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("This program is protected by copyright, do not redistribute. ");
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That command does not exist, do 'programs' for a list of actions.");
        }
        onCommandLineReturn();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate use of local functions. Also, you should avoid mutating `static` fields in more than 1 location either as it makes your program's flow hard to understand.

Comment: ok i'll keep that in mind, but visual studio did just add these for me when i was autocompleating the function so im a little confused

Comment: "visual studio did just add these for me" - Visual Studio does not generate local functions.

Comment: Command-line programs are supposed to be executed from the command line provided by Cmd.exe.  But that is not how programmers test them, VS is not anything like Cmd.exe.  Not like you can't make them work properly [both ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256385/17034).  But nobody bothers, there is no point to it when you can set a breakpoint at the end of Main().

Comment: i am trying to make my own custom one that doesn't require the cmd.exe. Thats the point, but thank you for notifying me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console applications close when they get to the end of `Main`. It's exiting after the `Console.ReadLine` in `onCommandLineReturn();`.

Add a `bool` variable called `keepLooping`, set it to `true`, and wrap your code in a `while(keepLooping)` statement. Somewhere in your program flow, check for input like "quit" or "exit" and set the `keepLooping` variable to `false`.

Here's an example of it in a dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Jguj5k

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed the entire thing!

Comment: Thanks - if this worked for you, please accept as an answer.